# jssor full height or full screen slider / possible?

Tags: jssor

is it possible to make this demo `http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.html` to full screen height ? like supersizes carousel `http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html`

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

please use following code to scale slider to full screen,

```
//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if (windowWidth) {
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var originalWidth = jssor_slider1.$OriginalWidth();
        var originalHeight = jssor_slider1.$OriginalHeight();

        var scaleWidth = windowWidth;
        if (originalWidth / windowWidth > originalHeight / windowHeight) {
            scaleWidth = Math.ceil(windowHeight / originalHeight * originalWidth);
        }

        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(scaleWidth);
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}

ScaleSlider();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

and wrap the slider container

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 50%; width: 5000px; text-align: center; margin-left: -2500px;">

        <!-- use 'margin: 0 auto;' to auto center element in parent container -->
        <div id="slider1_container" style="...margin: 0 auto;..." ...>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Please visit [Full Screen Slider](http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider.source.html) with source code.

Comment: thx, i just opened that demo html and replaced the code but somehow all width still 1300px any ideas ?

Comment: I got the same problem. Width 1300px. Somehow, container goes off the screen? any idea?

Comment: Please see http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider.source.html. Please update me if there is any problem.

Comment: still dont get any luck. only nav 1, 2, 3, 4 go down to bottom-center

slider goes to its origin size.

Comment: full screen slider shows a vertical scroll bar. Can we get rid of it?

Comment: add 'overflow: hidden' to body element. <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;">

Comment: for those who are facing problem of fixed width please replace the above code properly it will work ... and thanks @jssor for great work

Comment: On which file should I add the above js @jssor ?

Comment: @Andrew Lyndem Please open `view-source:http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider.source.html` with chrome browser.

Comment: I was using the jssor wordpress plugin and was having a hard-time finding a way to append the above to the script as it is dynamically generated. Figurd it out though :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a new api $ScaheHeight with Jssor Slider 17.0 or later.

```
//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider to scale along with window
function ScaleSlider() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if (windowWidth) {
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var originalWidth = jssor_slider1.$OriginalWidth();
        var originalHeight = jssor_slider1.$OriginalHeight();

        if (originalWidth / windowWidth > originalHeight / windowHeight) {
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleHeight(windowHeight);
        }
        else {
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(windowWidth);
        }
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}

ScaleSlider();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider-new-api.source.html

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers above, I got it working, but the "slider1_container" div should be wrapped like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">

    <div style="position: relative; left: 50%; width: 5000px; text-align: center; margin-left: -2500px;">


 <div id="slider1_container"> 
 ... 
 ... 
 </div>


 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I try to do this I get jquery error Uncaught Error: Cannot scale jssor slider, 'width' of 'outer container' not specified. Please specify 'width' in pixel. e.g. 'width: 600px;', So I am not able to set the width in %

Comment: Are you using the latest jssor version?