# Highcharts animation blue line and black line together follow by green line possible?

Tags: highcharts

Based on the highcharts as below,

```
[demo][http://jsfiddle.net/3xpyruLc/]
```

I want animation for the line RMG380/RMG500 first follow by MGO. Now the 3 lines is animation at the same time. Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this could be what you are looking for?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350831/jssor-full-height-or-full-screen-slider-possible