# Some slides portrait, some landscape - how to get Jssor to display them correctly?

Tags: jssor

My slides are different sizes, and orientations (some panoramas). I mean all are pics from a photo roll. Nearly all pics are bigger than the viewport in one way or another. I want them to be centered, have a correct aspect ratio, still have touch controls for iPhone, as well as the `< >` widgets (which go invisible by the way if the image is narrower than the width of the page) for desktop.

I can get full width, by specifying max-width in CSS. Full height is trickier. The "`Full Width Slider`" demo fixes `height` at `500px`, and trial and error only allows me to change that to another integer number rather than a percentage.

So I'm struggling to tweak the right options, and set the right style/css inline in the HTML.  Is there a better demo for me than "Full Width Slider" (http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.html)

It'd be great to pinch-zoom into images that are larger than the viewport, but that's secondary to getting my "fit" issues sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

Please set slider size to your screen size, and set $FillMode to 1.

To apply css tricks to set slider size, you can place jssor slider in a wrapper, and then scale the slider to available width of the wrapper.

See,

```
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
            else
                $JssorUtils$.$Delay(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
```

Reference: [jssor full height or full screen slider / possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350831/jssor-full-height-or-full-screen-slider-possible)