# JSSOR - Swapping width and height

Tags: jssor

after experimenting with jssor for a week or so, i did get the results i wanted on both desktop and mobile.

i used the code from
[JSSOR Full height full screen slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350831/jssor-full-height-or-full-screen-slider-possible)

i changed this line (original code)

```
if (originalWidth / windowWidth > originalHeight / windowHeight) {
```

to (modified code)

```
if (originalWidth / windowWidth < originalHeight / windowHeight) {
```

the only question i have now is, can the slider1_container height and width be swapped when it on the mobile in vertical mode? i am asking this because when in horizontal mode the app looks great. but in vertical mode, it only fills the height in the original full height code and fills the width in the modified code. in vertical mode, original code have overflows and modified code is too small.

i hope you get what i mean.

Comment: This is impact between width and height. If width is so much greater than height, it fits well on mobile in horizontal orientation. But in vertical orientation, it doesn't. I guess you want to rotate the slider to fit both orientations. Unfortunately there is no such option. You need to do this job by manual scripts of your own.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have tried doing it manually but it seems to be stopped by '_scaleWrapper' and 'innerWrapper' div tags. Because they inherited the width and height, and they don't have IDs after loading, i am unable to directly modify them. Any idea how do I access these 2 div tags?

Comment: $("slider1_container").children(0); $("slider1_container").children(0).children(0);

Comment: i have tried multiple methods including messing with the jssor.slider.js and js.utils.js to no avail. i am currently stuck at these few lines. can you explain why isn't this working? both gives a different result. `code    $("#slider1_container").css("width",windowWidth);     $("#slider1_container").css("height",windowHeight);   tempX = $('#slider1_container').css("width");     tempY = $('#slider1_container').css("height");     oriX = jssor_slider1.$GetOriginalWidth();     oriY = jssor_slider1.$GetOriginalHeight();`

Comment: It doesn't work to change 'width' and 'height' only. you'd try 'transform'

Comment: thanks for the reply. will try it out now.

Comment: hi. i have tried everything including scale, transition, rotate, manually changing it. i tried this in jssor.utils.js too `code _SelfSlider.$SetOriginalWidth = function (width) {
            $JssorUtils$.$CssWidth(elmt, width);
        };`it does change the size of the #slider1_container but not jssor_slider1. whenever i call the jssor_slider1.$setScaleWidth(x); it always refers to the $GetOriginalWidth().

Comment: Please don't call any method to rotate. You'd use your own scripts to operate on 'slider1_container' element.

Comment: thanks to your input, i have successfully managed to swap the width and height. the children function works. now i am faced with another slight problem. about the animation/easing in and out. lets say my image is 1920x1080. when it is scaled to fit into 1080x1920, it will become 1080x608 on display. the animation still animates for 1920 width. i have pin pointed the problem to this div debug-id="slide-container", as this is the place where the sliding take place. how do i shorten the width to slide?

Comment: It's the way it works, we cannot do anything else.

Comment: thanks for the help so far. i solved the lagging and flicker problem by setting HWA to false on mobile devices. I have managed to solved all my problems. i would like your opinion on this testing site. http://topshot.my/slideme/slideme2.html it is not complete, just a prove of concept for my boss. do you any better method to implement it?

Comment: Hi, pretty good work. Congratulations and thanks for your feedback. I will check HWA option for mobile device later.