# How change the property of gridslide

Tags: jquery, grid, styles, photo, jssor

I changed the property in .js end style but I not have success

I need help.

The grid is this http://www.jssor.com/demos/grid-slider.html

I need it to full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following links help.

[jssor full height or full screen slider / possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350831/jssor-full-height-or-full-screen-slider-possible)

http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider.source.html

Comment: Thanks so much guy you saved my life today.
if I could I gave you my liking but I'm still not released this new option!