# Creating a full screen responsive jssor slider with caption & thumbnails

Tags: jquery, jssor

So, I tried to create a full screen jssor slider following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350831/jssor-full-height-or-full-screen-slider-possible/23352018#23352018)
and it helped.

However, the contents inside the slider are not responsive. Please have a look at the [DEMO](http://www.morfys.com/projects/jssor/demos-jquery/full-width-slider.source.html)
of what I've achieved so far.

Since the slider uses pixels and not percentage, I had a hard time to make the contents inside the full screen slider to be responsive. It would be really helpful if anyone could solve the problem. I am trying to achieve something closely related to [this](https://www.freelancer.in/)
.

Besides, the official link for jssor full screen slider [here](http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider.source.html)
doesn't seem to work for me.

I am waiting on jssor himself to help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Jssor slider will always keep aspect ratio while scaling.

As size of browser screen is various, it cannot fit the screen exactly.

You can calculate to display the slider covering the whole screen, the slider will be partially hidden then.
Or you can display the slider totally in the screen with some blank space in the screen.